# Creating multiple plot per level of factor (trillis graph) in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba, charts, microsoft-excel-2013

Is there way to automate the process to make graphs like the following (also known as trallis graph) in excel ? I know there are some R interface with Excel (some of them need to be purchased), but I am interested in pure excel solution.

[image]

Lets say the data is organized as in the following columns, in long form:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With help of add ins (some need to be purchased other are free), you can create Trallis type plots.

One of important is RExcel. [Advanced graphs using Excel](http://excelgraphs.blogspot.com/) blog has some illustrations on how to create trallis plots and other utilities. For example:

Trallis scatter plot (http://excelgraphs.blogspot.com/2013/04/plotting-multiple-scatter-plots.html)

RExcel provides fundamental needs. I do not think not everything is possible in Menu mode with adds in but it provides code and you can twike with limited programing such as change color etc.